# Filter in aggrid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to get Filter like Excel in aggrid -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to pay for the Enterprise version.

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/filter-set-excel-mode/

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have an option to filter like excel.

1, you should purchase enterprise edition
2, there are two option in filter. One is windows like excel and other is mac like excel.

```
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'animal',
            filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                // can be 'windows' or 'mac'
                excelMode: 'windows',
            },
        }
    ],

   // other grid options ...
}
```

You can find more details in the documentation.

Comment: so far no one mentioned the most important factor that excel mode is always client side. all of your data must of present to do it